# Differences between cts:Element-walk and type-switch functionalities

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9

Could someone provide a better explanation between `cts:element-walk` and `typeswitch` functions?

I had tried to follow the Developer API.  However, I am not really satisfied with the instances for `cts:element-walk`. I would really appreciate if someone could help me to understand the pros and cons.

Which one is efficient for implementing the recursive calls and data transformations with each recursive call?

Answer (score 3):

If all you need to do is walk through an XML tree and do something for specific elements, `cts:element-walk` is going to be more efficient because it is optimized at the C++ layer.

If you want to do a complex transformation involving lots of different elements doing lots of different things, you could still code that in `cts:element-walk`, but you are likely to lose most of the efficiency benefit and your code is likely to be complex to understand.

Comment: would CTS:element-walk read only one node at a time or could it be acceptable to read the multiple nodes at the same time ? @mholstege suppose i have the multiple  child nodes inside the parent element ,every time when i find all my optional child elements , i need to create one element by replacing all the optional child elements and its data in the same order . would it be possible with cts:element-walk?

Answer (score 1):

[`cts:element-walk`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-walk) is a 'top down' one pass simple transformation.  Analogous with say java `stream().map()`   It can do a basic search/replace based on element names and  values.
cts:xxx are MarkLogic specific APIs.

[`typeswitch`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xquery-31-20170321/#id-typeswitch) is built into the XQuery language and is an *expression* that evaluates a single item (not necessarily a node or element) analogous to say a java 'switch' statement.

You use them very differently, for example you dont need to use a recursive algorithm for basic `cts:element-walk`s on the other hand, type-switch can distinguish between not only element and element names but also typed values (non element types), user defined and schema types.
But it doesn't actually 'do' anything so it must be used in a larger context (typically a recursive xquery function).

Due to this the amount of user supplied (hence interpreted) code required to perform similar actions is much larger for type-switch, so likely to be slower.
However `cts:element-walk` can be used in many cases type-switch can-

A) If you can easily do it with `cts:element-walk` -- do so

B) If not, dont.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However , I have some transformations which needs to achieve. If I  find the match for parent element ,I have to concatinate multiple  child elements  data together and concatenate as one element inside the parent element. Since CTS:element-walk would do linearly , can it accept more than one node at the same time ?